# Unity WebGL error net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I built a WebGL project and uploaded it into my website, it is working fine.

In the project, I have a coroutine that downloads a video from the internet

```
IEnumerator DownloadVideo(string video_download_link){
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(video_download_link);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    string savePath = Application.temporaryCachePath + "/myVideo.mp4";
    File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, www.downloadHandler.data);
```

and then it tries to play the video in a VideoPlayer:

```
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => File.Exists(savePath));
    videoPlayer.url = savePath;
    videoPlayer.Prepare();
    while(!videoPlayer.isPrepared) yield return null;
    videoPlayer.Play();
}
```

The video seems to be downloaded fine, but when it's going to be played, I get:

> GET http://www.mywebsite.com/tmp/myVideo.mp4 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: `The video seems to be downloaded fine`  How are you making this determination?  The 404 indicates the video can't be found.

Comment: As I said, the video seems to be downloaded fine, the problem is comes as a `byte[]` and I wasn't able to store it anywhere. I tried the store it in `savePath` but apparently it cannot be saved there and therefore it gives this error.

Comment: How are you determining that it's downloading fine if you can't store the result anywhere and you're getting an error indicating the video can't be found?

Comment: I'm downloading from Firebase Storage. I was getting CORS problem before, then I fixed it in the server and the CORS problem was gone. I also put some debugs after the download command. It is even hard to say if the download is fine but in editor it was working.